# How do I implement my Node.js code to work on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web

I have a node.js code that runs perfectly in terminal. How can I display the console.log section on localhost (then Heroku)?

I'm still beginner so express is difficult for me. Should I use that?
I tried Browserify too.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      var url = "URL";
      await page.goto(url);

      const eladok = await page.evaluate(() => 
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.shopname.fjump'))
        .map((eladok) => eladok.innerText.trim()));

      const hanyadik = await page.evaluate(() => 
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.shopname.fjump'))
        .map((hanyadik) => hanyadik.innerText.trim()));

      console.log('Összes ajánlat száma: ' + eladok.length);
      console.log('Helyezés: ');
      console.log(hanyadik.indexOf("usanotebook.hu") + 1);

      await browser.close();
})();
```

**I want to make a website that prompt the user for an URL then I store it to the "url" variable. The result is written below the text input.**

Comment: If you want a website, than you need to use http module to make a server. Than you can serve html page to prompt user for informations you want

Comment: How can i reach that express runs my code? And i can see the result in the browser's console.

Answer (score -2):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000

// "/" => "USA Note Book"
app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.send("USA Note Book")
});

// Tell Express to listen for requests from the App ("Starts Server").
app.listen(port, function(){
console.log("Server is open");
});

// Or the Other way

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(5000, () => console.log(`server is running on port ${5000}`));
```

Express is one of the things to install when working with the backend (I mean Node.js).
Is also a backend framework running on top of Node.js that means you must use it either ways.

```
// To install it: npm install express --save
```

I hope this information might be of help. Thank you

Comment: Use res.render("USA Note Book")

Comment: I think you totally misunderstood the whole thing, so thank you.

Comment: Sorry sir, if I totally misunderstand you, but if i got your question right is how do you implement your node.js code to work on your website you are creating, then res.render() will render your html codes on your website, so it will enable the page to be displayed with your browser. Thank you